# How to configure correctly the JBoss in the Intellij IDEA? I get Error:server instance not specified

Tags: java, gwt, jboss, intellij-idea, webserver

I cannot configure JBoss web server for the GWT application in Intellij IDEA.

IDEA tells me:

> Error: server instance not specified.

How to fix that? Any ideas?

[image]

[Photo in better quality](http://i032.radikal.ru/1208/51/1bd441a614a5.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the same window, select the server instance under JBoss Server Settings area.

[image: JBoss Server Settings]

Answer (score 2):

List of "Server instance" on Jboss Server Settings correspond to directory name of your Jboss instance.

Ex : "myInstanceJboss" and "anotherInstance" are visible in dropdown list if you have

$JBOSS_HOME/server/myInstanceJboss/

$JBOSS_HOME/server/anotherInstance/