# Error: Application Server not specified - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

When I configure the Tomcat in the IntelliJ IDEA, there have a issue I don't understand.

> Error: Application Server not specified

Before asking the question, I have searched the SO, found the related post:
[How to configure correctly the JBoss in the Intellij IDEA? I get Error:server instance not specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114556/how-to-configure-correctly-the-jboss-in-the-intellij-idea-i-get-errorserver-in)

But it is not fit me.

The snapshot:

[image]

---

**Attention**

I did not Configure the Application Server, because I can not choose the hidden directory path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the top where it says:
Application server: [          text box         ] <kbd>configure</kbd>

You need to specify the location of your local tomcat installation.

#### UPDATE

Per comments and updates, intelliJ somehow cannot locate tomcat installed under hidden folder.
Simply typing out the absolute path should work.

Comment: look at here, I can not find the path, how to configure it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016640/configure-the-application-server-can-not-find-the-tomcat-place-intellij-idea

Comment: Look at the link I comment, you can see the Tomcat9(I dnowload, I locate it under the `~/Library` )

Comment: I dont have a mac at hand, have you tried typing the absolute path to tomcat directory? like /Users/blabla/blabla/tomcat

Comment: If you have time, I suggest that you make some changes to the question to reflect the real problem behind it so that it can help someone who might have similar issues but could not find it. I will update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on "Run"
2. Click on "Edit Configuration"
3. Click on "+"
4. Scroll down to "Tomcat Server"
5. Select "Local or Remote"
6. Select "Configure" next to Application Server
7. Click "+"
8. Configure it to your extracted Tomcat Server

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/defining-application-servers-in-intellij-idea.html

Comment: but I can not find the Tomcat path, look at here my other post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016640/configure-the-application-server-can-not-find-the-tomcat-place-intellij-idea